# Two methods returning different types without parameters, how to call?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, obfuscation, ambiguity

There is some .net Dll library, this Dll contains a class with two methods with the same name, such as:

```
void b()
{

}

bool b()
{

}
```

It is not possible in C#, but it appear to be OK internally, how can I call one method from my code when adding such library?

I need the simplest way, I know it is OK using reflection, but are there any other easier way?

****EDIT****

I am getting this in the metadata of the library:

```
#region Assembly XXXX.dll, v xxxx
// C:\....................
#endregion


namespace XXXX.YYYYY
{
    public class a : IDisposable
    {

        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        public void b();
        public bool b();
        .
        .
        .
        .
        public void Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only possible if they are in two different classes, so use the class names and namespaces.

Comment: What does *it appear to be OK internally*? It's not OK. It's not possible in C#

Comment: I guess at least they are not public (because they are obfuscated). Do you want to use reflection?

Comment: No they are public, I am sure, and in the same class in the same namespace!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky and gdoron: This is *not* possible in C#, but *possible* in CLR and IL. Obfuscation tools usually perform such a tricks.

Comment: a good point is raised by @MD.Unicorn; if this is an obfuscated dll - and they have obfuscated the public API - then this probably isn't the dll you want. There should be a non-obfuscated one (or one where at least the public API is sane) somewhere. Of course, if this is a C++/CLI dll, or something written in IL and compiled in ILASM, or something compiled via reflection.emit, then: yeah, that's tough.

Comment: Thank's very much @MarcGravell, really I am working on reverse engineer something, so, this is what happened to me!

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan then let me state clearly: you probably ***shouldn't be trying*** to reverse engineer that. It quite plainly isn't intended to be used. If you had legitimate access to this, the API would be sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooh, that's horrible. The only way you can call that from C# is via reflection; you'd probably need to use `GetMethods()` and find the one you want from the array (the `GetMethod()` overloads may not love that).

Once you have the `MethodInfo`, you can either just use `Invoke`, or you can use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to get a typed delegate you can re-use. It depends how often you will be calling it, as to which of those is preferable.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible?!

Comment: @gdoron you could write that in IL and then use ILASM, or you can probably write it in C++; you can also do that via reflection.emit

Comment: Are there any other way :) I know the reflection will do it, but I need something easier.

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan "something easier" would be: not trying to work with obfuscated dlls. This is a pathological edge case - the C# language does not allow this scenario and does not try to make it easy.